# Analysing log files using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig Latin and I need to analyze a log file to check for error logs and warning logs.

How to do that ? What is the script for finding errors and warnings ?

Comment: Suggest you reading the documentation for [Apache Pig](https://pig.apache.org). This question is too broad to answer and is beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: Thank you sir! Sure I will read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would start off by `LOAD`-ing each line of a file as a string, then applying and extracting a regex pattern from each line, followed by a `FILTER` for errors and warnings.

Elasticsearch is more commonly used for log analysis instead of Hadoop tools, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yeah but I have a project which I need to do using Pig